# Can I change the maximum number of dependencies in a picklist?

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist

I hope you are well, I have the following problem. In a picklist with 347 values I need to add its dependencies from another picklist. The problem is that it has more than 300 item and Salesforce does not allow me to add a dependency if it has more than 300 values.

[image]

So, can I extend the maximum values to add a depezndence?

Any comments are welcome.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can raise a request to salesforce will increase the limit. Please refer this [Link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000338780&type=1) article will have detailed steps and considerations for picklist values increase.